# Правда ли, что, в MS SQL Server 2000, перестроение индексов возможно только их пересозданием?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Приведу пример. Когда-то давно, в таблице был создан один индекс, вчера столкнулся с проблемным запросом, не заметив этот индекс создал такой же, и что вы думаете? Да, он мне помог. А ещё, у меня каждый день выполняется скрипт для реиндексации.

Мне один человек говорил, что, перестроение кластерных индексов в MS SQL Server 2000 возможно только их пересозданием. Мой же индекс не кластерный.

Скрипт для реиндексации:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.spDBREINDEX

/*
  Created:  12/18/2002
  Created By:   AJ Ahrens - SQL DBA AT&T Labs x3375
  Purpose(s):   Dynamically reindex table(s)
*/

AS

DECLARE @TableName  VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @IndexName  VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @OrigFillFactor INTEGER
DECLARE @OuterCounter   INTEGER
DECLARE @InnerCounter   INTEGER
DECLARE @OuterLoop  INTEGER
DECLARE @InnerLoop  INTEGER
DECLARE @ClusteredYN    INTEGER
DECLARE @strSQL     NVARCHAR(2000)

SELECT SO.[name] tblName, MAX(SI.OrigFillFactor) OrigFillFactor, 
  '01/01/1900 12:00:00AM' ReIndexedDtTm, SI.[name] IndexName, 
  CASE WHEN SI.indid = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ClusteredYN
INTO #IndexedTables
FROM sysindexes SI
  LEFT JOIN sysobjects SO ON SI.[id] = SO.[id]
WHERE xtype = 'U' AND SI.indid <> 0 AND SI.indid <> 255
GROUP BY SO.[name], SI.[name], SI.indid

SET @OuterCounter = 1

SET @OuterLoop = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT tblName) FROM #IndexedTables)

  WHILE @OuterCounter <= @OuterLoop
    BEGIN
      SET @TableName = (SELECT TOP 1 tblName FROM #IndexedTables WHERE ReIndexedDtTm = '01/01/1900 12:00:00AM')
    SET @InnerCounter = 1
    SET @InnerLoop = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #IndexedTables WHERE tblName = @TableName)

    WHILE @InnerCounter <= @InnerLoop
      BEGIN
        SET @IndexName = (SELECT TOP 1 IndexName FROM #IndexedTables WHERE ClusteredYN = 1 
                AND tblName = @TableName AND ReIndexedDtTm = '01/01/1900 12:00:00AM')
        SET @ClusteredYN = 1

        IF RTRIM(@IndexName) IS NULL
          BEGIN
        SET @IndexName = (SELECT TOP 1 IndexName FROM #IndexedTables WHERE ClusteredYN = 0
                AND tblName = @TableName AND ReIndexedDtTm = '01/01/1900 12:00:00AM')
        SET @ClusteredYN = 0
          END

        SET @OrigFillFactor = (SELECT OrigFillFactor FROM #IndexedTables 
                WHERE tblName = @TableName AND ClusteredYN = @ClusteredYN
                    AND IndexName = @IndexName)

        SET @strSQL = 'DBCC DBREINDEX ' + '(' + CHAR(39) + @TableName + CHAR(39)
        + CHAR(44) + SPACE(1) + CHAR(39) + @IndexName + CHAR(39) + CHAR(44) 
        + SPACE(1) + CONVERT(VARCHAR(3), RTRIM(@OrigFillFactor)) + ')'

        PRINT @strSQL
        EXEC sp_executesql @strSQL

        UPDATE #IndexedTables SET ReIndexedDtTm = GETDATE() WHERE tblName = @TableName
        AND ClusteredYN = @ClusteredYN AND IndexName = @IndexName

        SET @InnerCounter = @InnerCounter + 1
      END

      SET @OuterCounter = @OuterCounter + 1
    END
```

Comment: Мне аж любопытно, кто в 2017 году плюсует вопрос про SQL Server выпущенный в далёком 2002 году (снятой с поддержки в 2008 и с расширенной поддержки в 2013)?

Comment: @NickProskuryakov То есть, по вашему, реиндексация не включает в себя перестроение индексов?

Comment: Найдите в сети 2005 и не мучайтесь. Он работает практически везде (кроме там 2016 винды) и довольно стабильно.

Comment: @NickProskuryakov Вы внимательно читали вопрос? Во первых, вопрос не в этом, а во вторых, я написал в вопросе что создал такой же индекс и это помогло.

Comment: @aaa прошу прощения прочел "не помог", ну и подумал что у вас старый индекс в плане остался.

Comment: @NickProskuryakov Он остался, я просто создал такой же и он мне помог. Добавил в вопрос скрипт для реиндексации.

Comment: что-то я не понял, а причём тут перестроение? вы же новый индекс создали, нет? вопрос в чём?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

DBCC DBREINDEX   - как раз устаревшая инструкция, которая перестраивает индекс, пересоздавая его заново (аналогична ALTER INDEX ... REBUILD)

DBCC INDEXDEFRAG  - это устаревшая инструкция (аналогична ALTER INDEX ... REОRGANIZE)

ALTER INDEX ... REORGANIZE/REBUILD появилось в 2005й версии

Так что в 2000м можно было также либо перестраивать, либо дефрагментировать (реорганизовывать)